# How to create a "unique" socket in zeromq?

Tags: zeromq

I'm experimenting with a simple actor model in haskell, where
each actor:

- is a haskell thread
- has a zeroMQ PULL socket upon which it receives messages

Some actors are "well known", have indefinite lifetimes, and
hence have their socket bound to a well known port. Other actors
are short lived and transient, and hence need a random free port
assigned to them.

I was previously unaware of the ability of zmq3 to allow binding
to an ephemeral port, as described here: 
     http://api.zeromq.org/3-2:zmq-tcp

Hence, for transient actors I currently have code that tries
to bind to a free port within a given range. This works as
intended, but brings to light a zmq behavior which causes me
problems: If a transient actor closes it's port and exits, and a
new transient actor starts, it's likely to bind to the same port
os the old one. In this circumstance any outstanding or
subsequent messages queued for the old actor will be received by
the new one.

How can I avoid this?

If I bound my transient actors sockets using the wildcard to get
a system assigned ephemeral port, would I still potentially see
this problem?

How can I generate a new unique PULL socket with the TCP
transport that is guaranteed to be distinct from any others?

Answer (score 0):

In general usage, you use `bind()` only for stable, "well known" actors, and you use `connect()` for transient actors. It seems a little weird if you need the port number for transient actors.

Also, perhaps you should add something to your protocol so that transient actors that are going away let the other side know, so that the other side won't continue to send them messages (which are then received by a new transient actor bound to the same port as the old one).

I think system-assigned ephemeral ports generally try not to reuse ports immediately, so that would likely also solve some of your problems.

Comment: _In general usage, you use bind() only for stable, "well known" actors, and you use connect() for transient actors_

A transient actor still needs to provide an address to which other
actors can send messages. It doesn't know who these will be, so
doesn't have anything to "connect" with.

I guess what I am saying is that I expect to connect() to things to
which I am sending messages. This may be from the "well know" actors
to the transient ones, or vice versa.

Comment: Your architecture still sounds weird to me. If other actors need to know the transient actor's address, you have to pass that address around to the other actors. Either those other actors have some stable address so you can send them the new address via ZeroMQ (in which case you don't need to send them the address since you could establish the connection from the side of the transient actor) or you have an out-of-band connection (in which case, why use ZeroMQ?). Remember that PUSH vs PULL and connect vs bind are orthogonal in ZeroMQ.

Comment: It doesn't seem weird to me :-) You don't need an out of band
connection. Consider this scenario: the transient actors would run on users PCs, starting and stopping as required - if they bind to an
address, they need ephemeral ports. They would discover each other via a well-known location service, but then connect directly. Hence for each pair of transient processes that need to communicate, one side must bind to an address.